# Using Postgres with Eventmachine

Tags: ruby, postgresql, asynchronous, eventmachine

Does anyone know of a good way to connect to postgres inside eventmachine.

I know there is an implementation bundled with eventmachine but i don't like the use of sockets.

I just want a normal connection which i can send queries to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, how else are you going to connect to Postgres if not via. Sockets?!  To my knowledge, Postgres *always* uses sockets, the only choice is whether to use TCP or Unix sockets, or SSL over TCP.

Comment: Uhm, sorry but im kinda new to this. Could you give me an example on how i can connect and query postgres in eventmachine?

Comment: From your question I'd assumed that EventMachine has already implemented the Postgres protocol?  Isn't there something in the E.M. docs?

Comment: Yes it has but as the documentation says it is `PROVISIONAL IMPLEMENTATION of an evented Postgres client.`. And the last commit to it was in 2009, and it uses the old `postgres-pr` gem.

I would like to use the "new" ruby-pg gem which has support for async connection but i am new to postgres and eventmachien so maybe you could mix together some kind of example if you are experienced with the gem?

Comment: Maybe you can - give it a try! ;-)